# Pandas subtracting group mean from colum value

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a dataset from a genechip, where 16 chips measure 1 tissue sample. I would like to subtract from each gene in each chip the mean of this gene over all the chips. Therefore I grouped by gene and calculated the mean. Now I want to take the original PM intensity value and subtract the Mean from this gene.
Thus i need to match the gene column with the the index from the table where i stored the mean value for this gene group and then subtract this value from the PM column.

```
totalgene  = genedata.groupby(genedata['GENE']).mean()[['PM','LOGPM']]

genedata['MEANNORM'] = genedata['PM'] - totalgene.ix[genedata['GENE']]['AVGPM']
genedata['MEANNORM'] = genedata['LOGPM'] - totalgene.ix[genedata['GENE']]['AVGLOGPM']
```

results in the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-08c1bb979f9c> in <module>()
----> 1 genedata['MEANNORM'] = genedata['PM'] - totalgene.ix[genedata['GENE'],'AVGPM']
      2 genedata['MEANNORM'] = genedata['LOGPM'] - totalgene.ix[genedata['GENE'],'AVGLOGPM']

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2417         else:
   2418             # set column
-> 2419             self._set_item(key, value)
   2420 
   2421     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2483 
   2484         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 2485         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   2486         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2487 

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   2633 
   2634         if isinstance(value, Series):
-> 2635             value = reindexer(value)
   2636 
   2637         elif isinstance(value, DataFrame):

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reindexer(value)
   2625                     # duplicate axis
   2626                     if not value.index.is_unique:
-> 2627                         raise e
   2628 
   2629                     # other

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in reindexer(value)
   2620                 # GH 4107
   2621                 try:
-> 2622                     value = value.reindex(self.index)._values
   2623                 except Exception as e:
   2624 

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in reindex(self, index, **kwargs)
   2360     @Appender(generic._shared_docs['reindex'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)
   2361     def reindex(self, index=None, **kwargs):
-> 2362         return super(Series, self).reindex(index=index, **kwargs)
   2363 
   2364     @Appender(generic._shared_docs['fillna'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in reindex(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2257         # perform the reindex on the axes
   2258         return self._reindex_axes(axes, level, limit, tolerance, method,
-> 2259                                   fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
   2260 
   2261     def _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value,

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _reindex_axes(self, axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy)
   2275             obj = obj._reindex_with_indexers({axis: [new_index, indexer]},
   2276                                              fill_value=fill_value,
-> 2277                                              copy=copy, allow_dups=False)
   2278 
   2279         return obj

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _reindex_with_indexers(self, reindexers, fill_value, copy, allow_dups)
   2369                                                 fill_value=fill_value,
   2370                                                 allow_dups=allow_dups,
-> 2371                                                 copy=copy)
   2372 
   2373         if copy and new_data is self._data:

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in reindex_indexer(self, new_axis, indexer, axis, fill_value, allow_dups, copy)
   3837         # some axes don't allow reindexing with dups
   3838         if not allow_dups:
-> 3839             self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)
   3840 
   3841         if axis >= self.ndim:

C:\Users\timothy\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py in _can_reindex(self, indexer)
   2492         # trying to reindex on an axis with duplicates
   2493         if not self.is_unique and len(indexer):
-> 2494             raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
   2495 
   2496     def reindex(self, target, method=None, level=None, limit=None,

ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

And i have no clue why?
Could somebody help?

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message,

Comment: done and apologies :)

Comment: I was thinking about trying to decipher this and provide you with some useful information... but I can't figure it out.  You'd be well served to read [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [**HowToAsk**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ill add more explanation to the question sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `transform` for an inline aggregate which returns a series that can be subtracted from original columns, *PM* and *LOGPM*:

```
genedata['MEANNORM_PM'] = genedata['PM'] - \
                            genedata.groupby(['GENE'])['PM'].transform('mean')

genedata['MEANNORM_LOGPM'] = genedata['LOGPM'] - \
                               genedata.groupby(['GENE'])['LOGPM'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: thanks for the help! definitely need to look into the transform function never used it before :)